# The name of a science fantasy trilogy

Tags: story-identification

The 1st book starts with the main character (Paul), a WWI soldier climbing a giant tree in the middle of the battlefield and finding a giants castle. Other episodes include Tik-Toks  and Paul on (John Carter's) Mars.

Comment: The answer below is correct, but just wanted to add that it's not a trilogy but a quadrilogy

Comment: Tetralogy, to be pedantic, is the only correct term.

Answer (score 12):

The [Otherland](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otherland) series by Tad Williams  :-)

Comment: Thank you, thank you. Now I can finish reading the dam thing.

Comment: I wouldn't bother.  ;-)  Weeell, it's ok, but about 4 times as long as it should be and half the characters could be dropped.